# New Ruby user trouble installing RVM

Tags: ruby, git, rvm, osx-lion

Before I start, let me say that I looked at all the similar questions and it appears that no one had this particular problem:

I installed git.

Next I ran this from the command line:

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
```

My result is

```
bash: line 151: git: command not found
bash: line 153: git: command not found

ERROR: Unable to clone the RVM repository, attempted both git:// and https://
```

What did I do wrong here? I am attempting to install this on osx Lion. 
Additionally, can someone explain to me what the beginning of the bash command does? `bash < <(...)`

Just for my own curiosity :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `git` installed first. The command executes the script downloaded with `curl` from the given url using `bash`. The <(...) is apparently used to provide a list of commands as per http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html.

Comment: I installed git first before attempting to install rvm

Comment: Can you invoke `git` from your terminal? Maybe it's some kind of problem with `PATH`?

Comment: What's an example of something I can try to test that?

Comment: Try just "git" or "git config --list".

Comment: Says `git: command not found` so... I'm guessing I installed it wrong?

Comment: That seems so. You need to somehow have `git` in your `PATH` for this so either reinstall or manually add the place where `git` lives to `PATH`. So ultimately it is a question about installing git on OSX Lion. Consider retagging, reformulating?

Comment: If I type in `/usr/local/git` it sees it as a directory

Comment: I uninstalled it completely and reinstalled it, git appears to work now

Answer (score 0):

You either installed git wrong, or it's not in your path. Have you installed XCode? It should automatically install git 1.7.4 and put it in your path. You'll also need to have XCode installed to be able to compile any ruby versions using RVM.

Comment: I havent installed XCode.. I was hoping to fix this without installing it.

Comment: You need XCode to compile Ruby.

Comment: the Tin Man is correct. Installing RVM will do you no good without installing gcc (which is most easily done by installing XCode). Without it, you won't be able to install any rubies, which make RVM pretty useless.